# Turtle 3D for generate trees C++ and Opengl and l-System

Tags: c++

I am programming c++ and opengl to create a 3D tree, for example I draw a line from `(2,5,4)` to `(4,2,1)` and I want to draw another line from `(4,2,1)` to `(x,y,z)` in the same direction with the same length. How can I calculate `x,y,z`?

Comment: You perform simple vector substraction and use the draw function...? Your question is very unclear. Could you maybe try and explain it?

Comment: (4,2,1)-(2,5,4)+(4,2,1)=(6,-1,-2)

Comment: @PawełStawarz  , i have the rule F1++F2^F3F4 with  + roatate in X axe and ^ roatate in z axe and F draw a line, so i start to drawa the first F1 form Point1 (0,0,0) to Point2 (0,1,0) , for  F2 the Point2 became the Point1 of F2. to calculate the seconde point of F2 i multiple the (0,1,0)-(0,0,0)+(0,1,0)=(0,2,0) by rotate in X axe and i draw my seconde line, now for F3  the point2 of F2 became point1 of F3. now  if i use the same simple vector substraction to find the seconde point of F3 the point does not belong to the line defined by point1 et point2 of F2

Comment: @Beta the point (6,-1,-2) belong to the line define by (2,5,4) and (4,2,1)

Comment: Yes, that is true. And it is the (x,y,z) you seek.